# How to match English word with its equivalent Accented characters in Python

Tags: python, non-ascii-characters, non-english

I am trying to automate an application, where it is as like google engine. When user enters "société" (Accented character), it gives details which has either "société"(Accented) or "societe" (English) in it.

So my job is to validate is details contains given keyword.  I dont have problem on comparing accented characters. EX: "société" = "société". But the case "société" == "societe" fails. Python code below:

```
 >>> "société".find("societe")
 -1 #Fail
 >>> "société".find("société")
 0  #Success
 >>>
```

So how to match equivalent english word in Accented characters.

Any help will be highly apreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to compare them directly, I would look into removing the accents before searching. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string

Comment: Should Gödel map to Godel or Goedel? The latter is standard, but the former is what you would get by simply stripping off accents. It seems like you need a dictionary of equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode/0.04.1):

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode(u"société")
societe
```

Comment: Yeap..this works form me..thanks a lot...

Comment: @GuruswamyBM: accept the answer if your problem is solved.